# What is Cumulative Binomial probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am new to this so don't know if I am asking the right question as I just read about its usage but didn't know what exactly a Cumulative Binomial probability is.

So my question is, What is Cumulative Binomial probabilities ? any example will be of great help.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean the cumulative distribution function $F(k;n,p)$ of the
(discrete) [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with number of trials $n \ge 0$ and success probability $0 \le p \le 1.\;$
The probability mass functions (PMF)  is
$$f(k;n,p) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} $$
and the CDF can be expressed with
[normalized incomplete Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function)

$$F(k;n,p) = \sum_{i=0}^{k}f(k;n,p) =  I_{1-p}(n-k,k+1)$$

Comment: Or more simply, if $f(k) = \Pr(X=k|n,p)$ then $F(k) = \Pr(X \le k|n,p)$

Answer (score 1):

I sense that you are implicitly asking what a cumulative density function is. I apologize if this is not the case, and you can ignore what follows.

Imagine that your Binomial random variable represents the number of heads you obtain while flipping some coin $n$ times (let's formally call this random variable $X$). Then, the cumulative density function (or CDF) is a function that tells you, for each natural number $k$, what is the probability that you will obtain 
*at maximum $k$ heads*. If your coin is biased and it has a probability of showing heads equal $p$, the definition the CDF is

$F(k) = \mathbb P (X \leq k)$.

This definition is general, it works for all random variables and not only Binomials! For the specific Binomial case, gammatester gave you the correct formula.